# Upload image in media wp api

Tags: wordpress, api, flutter

I am trying to upload an image to the media .. The image has been uploaded successfully, but the image appears broken and its size is very small. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: can you please elaborate where you're trying to upload using what package, and also add the code you've already tried

Comment: Please add code

Comment: var resposeimg =
    await http.post('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media',
        body: jsonEncode({
          "file" : file.path.split("/").last,
        }),
        headers: {
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
          'Connection': 'keep-alive',
          "content-type" : "image/${imgformat.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'jpg'), 'jpeg')}",
          'Content-Disposition' : 'attachment; filename=${file.path.split("/").last}',
          "Authorization": "Bearer ${widget.userToken}"
        })

Comment: this is my code